# Remove borders from a particular window

Tags: vim, gtk

```
# -- THEME AUTO-WRITTEN DO NOT EDIT
include "/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"

style "user-font" {
    font_name = "Droid Sans 10"
}

widget_class "*" style "user-font"

gtk-font-name="Droid Sans 10"

include "/home/david/.gtkrc.mine"

style "vimfix" {
  #NOT WORKING
  GtkWindow::borderWidth = 0
}

widget "vim-main-window.*GtkForm" style "vimfix"

# -- THEME AUTO-WRITTEN DO NOT EDIT
```

That is my .gtkrc-2.0. How can I make gvim's window have no borders, or have a border width of 0?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at what other themes do.

With [the theme I use](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=121685), every window (including GVim) has only a 1px black border.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want all windows, I want just Gvim.